# Why is accessing mapped network drives slow from cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I have a mapped network drive (F:) on Windows 7 that I can access very quickly from cmd.exe. For examle `dir f:` returns instantaneously.

But from cygwin, `ls /f` takes 20 seconds.

From cygwin:

`$ uname
CYGWIN_NT-6.1

$ mount -p
Prefix              Type         Flags
/                   user         binmode

$ mount
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
F: on /f type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)

$ time ls /f
...
real    0m20.951s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.030s`

Any thoughts on the cause or how I can debug it?

Comment: It’s instant for me, but I use Windows 10. Is your Cygwin up to date?

Comment: @DanielB It's a very recent install of Cygwin (last couple of weeks).

Comment: It looks a timeout. lt is looking some data from windows that it does not receive. Do you have the same problem with new directories ? `mkdir /f/prova; time ls /f/prova`

Comment: @matzeri Thanks for the comment. Following your suggestion, I found both the `mkdir` and the `ls` returned very quickly (~200ms).